# Как сделать модальное окно на vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

Как сделать универсальное модальное окно на vue. Но так что бы это была одна компонанта окна на страницы, а остальные компоненты
, возможно не связанные с ней иерархически, моглибы это окно-компоненту открывать и закрывать?

*Т.е. я видел много примеров как сделать модальное окно когда оно всегда встроено в компоненту которая будет его вызвать, а как сделать если компонента вызвающая открытие окна не связана иерархией с комопнентой самого модального окна?*

**Так же в окно хочется передавть vue шаблоны....**

Answer (score 2):

в стандартной документации, есть пример [модалки](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html) на vue

это абсолютный стейтлесс компонент, там используются слоты. Внутрь слотов можно поместить что угодно.